# How to add some html element to jquery uidialog

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-dialog

Is it possible to add some html element when uidialog is displayed. I want to add logo image to the top-right corner. Is it possible?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can modify the DOM after the dialog is created. I have done a little example for you so you can get a hint about how to-do

http://jsfiddle.net/CH5Yp/

```
$(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
        create: function(){
            var logo = $("<div/>").addClass("logo");
            $(this).append(logo);
        }
    });
});
```

And the CSS

```
.logo{
    background: #FF0000;
    width:50px;
    height:10px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign an ID to the div it creates. Once you've invoked the dialog, you could probably append the HTML/nodes you want to the div. Set the proper CSS you want to get it to show in the upper left.

There may be a way to do it with themeing. See http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `open` event of dialog

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({

    /* other dialog options*/


   open: function(event, ui) {

       var logo=''; /* ?? not sure of logo source */
      $(this).append( logo);

    }
});
```